# My program seems inefficient

Tags: java, performance, swing, methods

I am a beginner and I have a program that is a game where you get from one point to the other. You are a green block and you avoid the red blocks. But I don't know how to create another moving red block without creating another method `enemyMovement2()`, which just seems inefficient, because what if I wanted to create many of these enemies. Is there any way to make an `arraylist` of this behavior?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {
    private static boolean dead = false;
    private static boolean won = false;

    boolean isPaused=false;
    boolean hasStarted=false;
    int level = 1;

    boolean powerUpIsEaten;
    boolean keepPowerUpOffScreen;
    int powerupx;
    int powerupy;
    int powerupwidth=20;
    int powerupheight=20;

    int winningx;
    int winningy;
    int winningwidth;
    int winningheight;

    int losingx;
    int losingy;
    int losingwidth;
    int losingheight;

    int losing2x;
    int losing2y;
    int losing2width;
    int losing2height;

    int losing3x;
    int losing3y;
    int losing3width;
    int losing3height;

    int losing4x;
    int losing4y;
    int losing4width;
    int losing4height;

    int losing5x;
    int losing5y;
    int losing5width;
    int losing5height;


    int enemywidth; 
    int enemyheight;

    int userwidth; 
    int userheight;


    ArrayList<Integer> badRectangles = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int x = 1, y = 1;

    int enemyX=400, enemyY=100;

    int velx=0, vely=0;

    boolean hasWon = false, hasDied = false;

    int movementcounter=0;

    private void move() throws InterruptedException {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

        if (vely > 0){
            if(y>700-userheight *2){        
            }
            else{
                y = y + 5 + movementcounter/300;
            }
        }
        if (vely < 0){
            if(y<0){        
            }
            else{
                y = y - 5 - movementcounter/300;
            }   
        }
        if (velx > 0){
            if(x>1200-userwidth){   
            }
            else{
                x = x + 5 + movementcounter/300;
            }
        }
        if (velx < 0){
            if(x<0){
            }
            else{
                x = x - 5 - movementcounter/300;
            }
        }
        if(isInARectangle()){
            hasDied=true;
        }
        if(isInWinningArea()){
            x=0;
            y=0;
            hasWon=true;
        }
        movementcounter++;
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        getValues(level);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 30)); 
        if(level==5){
            g2d.drawString("Congratulations", 550, 350);
            this.won=true;

        }
        else if(hasStarted
                && !isPaused){
            eatPowerup();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            for(int i=1; i<=level; i++){
                g2d.fillRect(badRectangles.get(4 * i - 4),badRectangles.get(4 * i - 3),badRectangles.get(4 * i - 2),badRectangles.get(4 * i - 1));
            }
            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2d.fillRect(winningx, winningy, winningwidth, winningheight); //WINNING RECTANGLE
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillRect(enemyX, enemyY, enemywidth, enemyheight); //ENEMY
            enemyMovement();

            if(!hasDied){
                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2d.fillRect(x, y, userwidth, userheight); //USER
            }
            if(hasWon
                    && !hasDied){
                level++;
                if(level==2){
                    enemyX=1000;
                    enemyY=0;
                }
                if(level==3){
                    enemyX=700;
                    enemyY=0;
                }
                if(level==4){
                    enemyX=400;
                    enemyY=100;
                }
                powerUpIsEaten=false;
                hasWon=false;
                keepPowerUpOffScreen=false;
            }
            if(hasDied){
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.drawString("You died", 500, 300); //LOSING SEQUENCE
                this.dead=hasDied;
            }
            if(!powerUpIsEaten
                    && level>1
                    && !keepPowerUpOffScreen){
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.fillRect(powerupx, powerupy, powerupwidth, powerupheight);
            }
            else{
                keepPowerUpOffScreen=true;
                powerUpIsEaten=false;
            }
        }
        if(isPaused){
            g2d.drawString("PAUSED", 450, 300);
        }
        if(!hasStarted){
            g2d.drawString("PRESS UP TO START", 450, 300);
        }
    }
    public void eatPowerup(){
        if(powerupx<x + userwidth + 5
                && powerupx>x
                && powerupy<y + userheight + 5
                && powerupy>y){
            powerUpIsEaten=true;
            powerupx=0;
            powerupy=1000;
            enemyX=0;
            enemyY=0;
        }
        else{

            powerUpIsEaten=false;
        }
    }
    public boolean isInWinningArea(){
        if(x<winningx + winningwidth - userwidth
                && x>winningx
                && y<winningy + winningheight-userheight
                && y>winningy){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean isInARectangle(){
        if((x > losingx-userwidth
                && x < losingx + losingwidth
                && y > losingy-userheight
                && y < losingy + losingheight)
                || x > losing2x-userwidth
                && x < losing2x + losing2width
                && y > losing2y-userheight
                && y < losing2y + losing2height
                || x > losing3x-userwidth
                && x < losing3x + losing3width
                && y > losing3y-userheight
                && y < losing3y + losing3height
                || x > losing4x-userwidth
                && x < losing4x + losing4width
                && y > losing4y-userheight
                && y < losing4y + losing4height){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
    public void getValues(int level){
        if(level==1){

            winningx=550;
            winningy=550;
            winningwidth=100;
            winningheight=100;

            losingx=200;
            losingy=100;
            losingwidth=200;
            losingheight=200;

            enemywidth=60; 
            enemyheight=60;

            userwidth=50; 
            userheight=50;

        }
        if(level==2){

            winningx=1000;
            winningy=500;
            winningwidth=200;
            winningheight=200;

            losingx=200;
            losingy=100;
            losingwidth=200;
            losingheight=200;

            losing2x=700;
            losing2y=500;
            losing2width=300;
            losing2height=200;

            enemywidth=60; 
            enemyheight=60;

            userwidth=50; 
            userheight=50;

            powerupx=900;
            powerupy=100;

        }
        if(level==3){

            winningx=1000;
            winningy=500;
            winningwidth=200;
            winningheight=200;

            losingx=200;
            losingy=100;
            losingwidth=200;
            losingheight=200;

            losing2x=700;
            losing2y=500;
            losing2width=300;
            losing2height=200;

            losing3x=100;
            losing3y=100;
            losing3width=100;
            losing3height=450;

            enemywidth=60; 
            enemyheight=60;

            userwidth=50; 
            userheight=50;

            powerupx=100;
            powerupy=600;
        }
        if(level==4){

            winningx=1000;
            winningy=500;
            winningwidth=200;
            winningheight=200;

            losingx=200;
            losingy=100;
            losingwidth=200;
            losingheight=200;

            losing2x=700;
            losing2y=500;
            losing2width=300;
            losing2height=200;

            losing3x=100;
            losing3y=100;
            losing3width=100;
            losing3height=450;

            losing4x=900;
            losing4y=300;
            losing4width=500;
            losing4height=100;

            enemywidth=60; 
            enemyheight=60;

            userwidth=50; 
            userheight=50;

            powerupx=600;
            powerupy=500;
        }
        if (level==5){

        }
        badRectangles.clear();
        badRectangles.add(losingx);
        badRectangles.add(losingy);
        badRectangles.add(losingwidth);
        badRectangles.add(losingheight);

        badRectangles.add(losing2x);
        badRectangles.add(losing2y);
        badRectangles.add(losing2width);
        badRectangles.add(losing2height);

        badRectangles.add(losing3x);
        badRectangles.add(losing3y);
        badRectangles.add(losing3width);
        badRectangles.add(losing3height);

        badRectangles.add(losing4x);
        badRectangles.add(losing4y);
        badRectangles.add(losing4width);
        badRectangles.add(losing4height);

        badRectangles.add(losing5x);
        badRectangles.add(losing5y);
        badRectangles.add(losing5width);
        badRectangles.add(losing5height);
    }
    public void enemyMovement(){

        if(enemyX<x){
            enemyX= enemyX+1 + movementcounter/300;
        }
        if(enemyX>x){
            enemyX=enemyX-1 - movementcounter/300;
        }
        if(enemyY<y){
            enemyY=enemyY + 1 + movementcounter/300;
        }
        if(enemyY>y){
            enemyY=enemyY -1 - movementcounter/300;
        }
        if(x<enemyX+enemywidth
                && x>enemyX-userwidth
                && y<enemyY+ enemyheight
                && y>enemyY-userheight){
            hasDied=true;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        switch( key ) { 
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            isPaused=false;
            hasStarted=true;
            vely = -1;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            vely = 1;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            velx = -1;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
            velx = 1;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_P:
            isPaused=true;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        velx = 0;
        vely = 0;

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Square Game");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(1200, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.BLUE );

        while (!dead
                && !won) {

            game.move();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should consider the difference between inefficient and poor design. Your question seems to be dealing with the latter.

Comment: Working Code. Why not try Code Review?

Comment: Avoid using `paint` and consider `paintComponent` instead. Avoid `KeyListener` and consider using [the Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead

Comment: You're in an OO environment, so every thing should be objects, so when you want to create more, you just make a new instance

Comment: You should also have different views for different requirements, like menu, game etc, instead of putting all your logic in a single component. Swing is also not thread safe, so you should be careful using a `Thread` for this type of work and instead, consider using a Swing `Timer` instead. Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Answer (score 4):

That's a *ton* of code! But here's a quick glimpse at what you're failing to realize.

***Some game objects are `Movable`.***

So, make a `Movable` `interface` which each movable GO implements. Then you just iterate over the `Movable`s and `movableGameObject.move()` them.

Example:

```
public interface Movable {
    void move();
}

class Player extends GameObject implements Movable {

    @Override
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Player moving...");
    }
}

class Enemy extends GameObject implements Movable {

    @Override
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Enemy moving...")
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Arrays.asList(
        new Movable[] { 
            new Player(), new Enemy() 
        }
    ).forEach(Movable::move);
}
```

As expected, this gives the output...

```
Player moving...
Enemy moving...
```